# String split after a character

Tags: vb.net, string, .net-2.0

Hi I have a string like this

```
MRP^1^1~MRP|MRP+1^1^1~MRP+1|MRP+2^1^1~MRP+2|MRP+3^1^1~MRP+3|MRP+4^1^1~MRP+4
```

I want to split it and get the into an array like this in a single line operation.

```
MRP
MRP+1
MRP+2
MRP+3
MRP+4
```

Can any one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do it using Regex :)

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click

        '~~> Input string
        Dim strSample As String = "MRP^1^1~MRP|MRP+1^1^1~MRP+1|MRP+2^1^1~MRP+2|MRP+3^1^1~MRP+3|MRP+4^1^1~MRP+4"

        Dim pattern As String = "(MRP\+?[0-9]?)\^1\^1\~"

        Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(strSample, pattern)

        For Each match As Match In matches
            MessageBox.Show (Match.Groups(1).Value)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT**

There can be one more way (A bit long winded though...)

You can use **String.Replace** to replace "**^1^1~**" by "**|**" so you have just 1 delimiter and then use Split to extract unique values. But then Like I mentioned above, that is kind of long winded. :)

HTH

Sid

Answer (score 1):

While this line of code will give you the result you seek, it may not be the best approach since I don't know how the data may variate nor what defines it, perhaps a little more insight on what you're trying to accomplish and where does that string come from may help us give you a better answer.

```
Dim resultArray = myCurrentString.Split(New Char() {"~", "|"}).Where(Function(str) Not str.Contains("^")).ToArray
```

Comment: I am using 2.0 I could not find Where.

Comment: oops, I was using Entity Framework there and I don't think `EF` works on .NET 2.0, I think it's 3.5 on. I hardly doubt there'd be a way of doing that in just one line for 2.0. You'll need a bucle.

Comment: Hey I got it. But i did it by using a loop.